# Why can't rendering HTML page in React application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 3 components in my React application that I use for Nav Bar.
In each component, there is a div element with id = 'root'

**Index.html** 
 
`<div id="root"></div>`

This is how it looks my App.js - 
 
**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './Home';
import {Department} from './Department';
import {Employee} from './Employee';
import {Navigation} from './Navigation';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <h3 className="m-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
          React JS Tutorial
      </h3>

    <Navigation/>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' component={Home} exact/>
      <Route path='/department' component={Department}/>
      <Route path='/employee' component={Employee}/>
    </Routes>

    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Example of Department Component:

**Department.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Department extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="mt-5 d-flex justify-content-left">
                This is Department page
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Home } from './Home';


//ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
  
  const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
  root.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementsByClassName('root'));
```

I tried to use ReactDOM instead but without any success, this is how it looks

[image]

**Update Solved** 
The problem was that I route by component instead element 
**Wrong** `<Route path='/department' component={Department}/>` 
**Correct** `<Route path='/department' element={<Department/>}/>`

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) doesn't return a single element but multiple. So either add an index like `getElementsByClassName('root')[0]` or use another function.

Comment: "In each component, there is a div element with id = 'root'" - why? Ideally, you should only have a single element for each unique Element ID. There is no reason for your react components to render elements with id `root`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.
I mean I use div in each element but have only one root in my index.html file.
By the way, I added document.getElementsByClassName('root')[0]) or document.getElementsById('root') but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** 
The problem was that I route by component instead element 
**Wrong** `<Route path='/department' component={Department}/>` 
**Correct** `<Route path='/department' element={<Department/>}/>`

Answer (score -2):

You are using `getElementsByClassName`, but your div: `<div id="root"></div>` does not have a property `class="root"`

use `getElementById("root")` instead.

Comment: I'm Also tried by **Id**

Comment: DId You write it correctly? Because the method is getElementById("root"), and getElementsById("root") is undefined

Comment: Yes, I write this in comment and try this:

//ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Then what is your problem? I see in the photo of your page that the APP component is showed, do you want to see the Department component in the screen?

Comment: Yes, 3 components have element div.
for example, when I navigate to the department route, I want that showed 'This is Department page"

Comment: In your navbar add some Links, something like: ```<Link to="/department">Department</Link>```